# Passing argument to array of function pointers

Tags: c, arrays, arduino, function-pointers

I am writing a program in C which uses an array of function pointers. If I do not include an argument I am able to call the functions with my code without an issue.

```
int (*functionsArray[2][3])() = {
  {functionOne,functionTwo,functionThree},
  {functionFour,functionFive,functionSix}
};
```

However when I try and pass the argument `int x`:

```
int (*functionsArray[2][3])(int x) = {
  {functionOne,functionTwo,functionThree},
  {functionFour,functionFive,functionSix}
};
```

I get an error:

```
invalid conversion from 'int (*)()' to 'int (*)(int)'
```

Also none of these functions return an int, shouldn't I be able to declare them as void?

```
void(*functionsArray[2][3])(int x) = {
  {functionOne,functionTwo,functionThree},
  {functionFour,functionFive,functionSix}
};
```

Trying this results in an error:

```
 error: invalid conversion from 'int (*)()' to 'void (*)(int)'
```

Thanks.

Comment: Show us at least `functionOne` and show us at which line you get the error.

Comment: `functionOne`, `functionTwo`, ... should have all exactly the same prototype. The prototype should be same as the prototype you use for the array.

Comment: Have you tried reorganising the parentheses, maybe something like (void(*functionsArray(int x)))[2][3]) = ... .  Secondly, and far more importantly, I would STRONGLY recommend creating a typedef for the function pointer, so the usage can be straight firmware array declaration.

Answer (score 1):

That will work fine, *provided* you declare the functions correctly:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int functionOne(int x)   { return 1; }
int functionTwo(int x)   { return 2; }
int functionThree(int x) { return 3; }
int functionFour(int x)  { return 4; }
int functionFive(int x)  { return 5; }
int functionSix(int x)   { return 6; }

int (*functionsArray[2][3])(int x) = {
    {functionOne,  functionTwo,  functionThree},
    {functionFour, functionFive, functionSix}
};

int main (void) {
    printf ("%d\n", (functionsArray[0][1])(99));
    printf ("%d\n", (functionsArray[1][2])(99));
    return 0;
}
```

The output of that program is `2` and `6`.

---

It will also work if you want *no* return value:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void functionOne(int x)   { puts ("1"); }
void functionTwo(int x)   { puts ("2"); }
void functionThree(int x) { puts ("3"); }
void functionFour(int x)  { puts ("4"); }
void functionFive(int x)  { puts ("5"); }
void functionSix(int x)   { puts ("6"); }

void (*functionsArray[2][3])(int x) = {
    {functionOne,  functionTwo,  functionThree},
    {functionFour, functionFive, functionSix}
};

int main (void) {
    (functionsArray[0][1])(99);
    (functionsArray[1][2])(99);
    return 0;
}
```

That program *also* outputs `2` and `6`, as expected.

---

It all comes down to ensuring that the function declarations match the type given in the array.

Comment: gee I feel dumb.
That fixed it up, thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

When you declare an array:

```
int (*functionsArray[2][3])(int x) = 
{
   {functionOne,functionTwo,functionThree},
   {functionFour,functionFive,functionSix}
};
```

every element of the array has to be of type  `int (*)(int)`. Otherwise, the compiler correctly reports an error.

Take a simple case:

```
void foo()
{
}

int (*fp)(int x) = foo;
```

should result in the same compiler error because you are trying to initialize a variable of type `int (*)(int)` using `foo`, whose type is `void (*)()`.